# how do I force to assign the value to a constant?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm not managing to assign a value. recognizes me "category" as a constant. have I tried with as? but, of course, he tells me "Use of undeclared type 'category"

```
class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelSubtitle: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

// assembled the cell
func updateCell(withFeedItem feedItem: RSSFeedItem) {
    var imageLink = ""
    var category = ""

    for media in (feedItem.media!.mediaThumbnails)! {
        imageLink = media.attributes?.url ?? "No image"
    }
    for categories in feedItem.categories! {
        category = categories.value ?? "None"

        guard let mediaThumbnails = feedItem.media?.mediaThumbnails,
            let categories = feedItem.categories else { return }

        for media in mediaThumbnails {
            imageLink = media.attributes?.url ?? "No image"
        }
        for category in categories {
            category = category.value ?? "None"
        }
    }

    self.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageLink), completed: nil)
    self.labelTitle.text = feedItem.title
    self.labelSubtitle.text = feedItem.description
    self.category.text = category
}
```

}

Comment: @mag_zbc I wrote the code. I put the photo to show the error. I'm sorry

Comment: @mag_zbc I think he posted image just to show an error on which line is happen, full code is above

Comment: @vpoltave Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-05-17 10:49:01.798202+0200 News EI[2831:815672] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You have to use if let for fetch media thumbnails then iterate or just get lastObject or firstObject.

Comment: @vadian edit my question. thanks for observation and sorry

Comment: Now the question makes no sense at all. Please ask a new question and delete this one.

Comment: @vadian does not cancel for this reason: you cannot delet this question as other have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an Exception Breakpoint enabled.  This will pause execution as soon as an error is thrown. Just like if you had a breakpoint set at this point of your code.
You can either (1)disable it or (2)press "Continue" to proceed with the crash and get the debugger output.

[image]

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-05-17 10:49:01.798202+0200 News EI[2831:815672] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (I insert !)

Answer (score 1):

Force unwrapping should be avoided. In your loops you are forcefully unwrapping feedItem.categories and feedItem.media?.mediaThumbnails. If those are optionals, then there should be some reason for that. You should first use guard or if let statements, so you will be sure those are not nil and be able to work with them however you want. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455123/how-to-avoid-force-unwrapping-a-variable) more about how to do safe unwrapping.